# Printing autocomplete info on current option in fish shell

Tags: shell, autocomplete, options, fish

When writing a command with a `-` option and pressing tab, a list of possible completions with short explanations of what the options do is displayed. Is there a way to make this list also contain the currently typed option?

E.g., writing `grep -r` and hitting tab displays

```
-rA                               (Print NUM lines of trailing context)
-ra                                       (Process binary file as text)
-rB                                (Print NUM lines of leading context)
-rb                                      (Print byte offset of matches)
…and 32 more rows
```

but I would like it to display

```
-r                       (Read files under each directory, recursively)
-rA                               (Print NUM lines of trailing context)
-ra                                       (Process binary file as text)
-rB                                (Print NUM lines of leading context)
-rb                                      (Print byte offset of matches)
…and 32 more rows
```

Cheers,

Hassanbot

Comment: You may want to flag the moderator to move your question to stackoverflow. More fish traffic there.

Comment: @glennjackman: this would be off-topic for Stack Overflow, not unless there is a coding component to this.

Comment: There are subcommunities on SO that are more relaxed about that. Fish is one. There's lots of questions about editors like vim on SO that more properly belong on superuser but historically are allowed. The fish experts are on SO so that's the best place to ask.